# Ошибка в get запрос

Tags: php, angularjs

Ошибка в запроса как исправит?

```
 $http.get('http://example.com/get_phone_number.php?number=*100#&name='+name).success(function(data) {
  //               console.log(data);
});
```

ошибка после # такие знак не работает

Comment: Просто экранируйте этот символ

Comment: Как? Это возможно

Comment: вот после # такие знаки name=test не работает

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуй использовать функцию: encodeURIComponent

Пример использования: http://javascript.ru/encodeuricomponent

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Хорошо, я вас понял, спасибо.